# How to get the original word from trans() Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, translation

The user should give his country name, the problem is that all countries name are translated to different languages, and I must re-trans to englisch to compare the name with the name in my database.
I did like that but it doesn't work  :

```
$translated_country = $this->get('translator')->trans($q_country, array(), null, 'en_US');
                $countries          = array("A, B, C");

                if( in_array($translated_country, $countries))
                {}
```

For example I have messages.de.yml
Germany : Deutschland
I want that when the user enters Deutschland , In my code I get Germany

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a match in the EN locale for each country translated into the other languages you support.

```
# messages.en.yml
deutschland: germany
Германия: germany
russland: russia
Россия: russia

# messages.de.yml
germany: deutschland
russia: russland

# messages.ru.yml
russia: Россия
germany: Германия

$toTranslate = 'deutschland';

$translator  = $this->get('translator');
$translation = $translator->trans($toTranslate, array(), null, 'en_US');

/** $translation should be 'germany' */
```

Comment: is there some easy way bc It's simple to solve and also It doesn't need extra extension for a simple translation

Comment: You're just trying to get it to translate from the User's locale back to english to compare with the database, correct?

Comment: right, in my database the name are in english and in my autocomplete i display the name in different language, so when the user choose in the autocomplete "Deutschland" I want to tranlate it and get "Germany"